# English words for describing ambient conditions

Tags: dummy-it, lexicon

There are two uses for the temperature terms *hot*, *warm*, *cold* and *cool*. One use refers to the state of a person or thing anaphorically or deictically, and one refers to the ambient temperature and is typically signaled by locative adverbs.

> 1. It is cold, this soup.
> 2. It is cold here today.

I was wondering which of the following adjectives have sensible uses in statements about ambient conditions or weather reports and could potentially be used in syntactic frames as in number 2, above (e.g., *It is dry here today in Boston*). Which adjectives are restricted to sentence 1? Which are restricted to sentence 2?

*damp*

*humid*

*tepid*

*dry*

*lukewarm*

*icy*

*suitable*

*burning*

*fresh*

*uncomfortable*

*moist*

*clammy*

*fiery*

*ice cold*

*stinging*

Comment: I suggest you google each one: cold soup/cold weather. etc. etc.  Also, we don't say "sensible uses". We'd say: uses with meaning or meaningful uses. I doubt for example that you will find much: moist soup or stinging soup.

Comment: "This soup is cold" is more common than "it's cold, this soup"

Comment: @Lambie Not to be difficult, but isn't this the exact forum where intricate lexicological questions such as these would be expected to be asked? Also, your Google test, even if conducted on a large scale, would tell us very little about the lexical properties of the words listed here.

Comment: You are the one asking an "intricate lexicological question". Are you saying your question is invalid?? Are you not hoisting yourself on your own petard? It is cold, the soup. contains no locative adverb. locative adverbs refer to **locations**. There are too many fingers in this soup. [joke]

Comment: @Lambie As I understand it, the question is about what words you can use in constructions like "It is X here today," where "it" is used as a dummy subject rather than as an ordinary pronoun (e.g. "It is cold here today").

Comment: (Sentences like (1)--"It's cold, this soup"--are examples of "right dislocation," a construction fairly common in conversational speech but rare in formal writing; here "this soup" is effectively tacked on to the end of the sentence to specify the referent of the pronoun "it," which isn't a dummy subject because it inflects for person and number: compare "He's a famous actor, John Wayne" or "They're good people, those firemen.")

Comment: @alphabet You are missing the point: since this is about weather and soup, regardless of the dummy it, many of those adjectives don't work in replacing: It is **cold** here today. You wouldn't say: "It's stinging or fiery here today". Or: "It is fiery, this soup". This is a semantics issue not a grammar one. The only way to figure it out is to put weather in one column and soup in the other preceded by each of those adjectives, and then tell the OP which ones don't work. Are you prepared to do that?? :)

Comment: Most combinations could work given the right situation. There are many substances called "soup" other than broth: an explosives expert might complain of nitroglycerine "it's damp, this soup", meaning it has water in it. "Fiery" could refer to spiciness. And "It's stinging, this soup" could relate to the rural delicacy [nettle soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nettle_soup).

Comment: "It is clammy, this chowdah."

Comment: Your *it* in (1) is anaphoric (*it* refers to *this soup* — as in *This soup is ____* ). So just fill in the blank to see what works. Some of these would be odd expressions, but the only one that doesn’t really work is *This soup is uncomfortable* (unless the soups has feelings).